# SQL condition - starts with a dynamic value

Tags: sql, db2, sql-like

I am writing a DB2 Stored procedure where I need to have a condition that select all values from table 1 and table 2 where table1.column_a starts with table2.column_b.

```
select * from table1 T1, table2 T2 where T1.column_a like T2.column_b + '%'
```

I tried playing around the above SQL but it seems like an invalid SQL. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: The problem is your `like` statement

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `concat()` function or `||` concatenation operator.  `+` for string concatenation is used by SQL Server and similar databases.

I would phrase this as a `join`:

```
select *
from table1 T1 join
     table2 T2 
     on T1.column_a like concat(T2.column_b, '%');
```

Comment: I used your suggestion. However, I get an error while deploying the stored proc. 'AN OPERAND OF LIKE IS NOT VALID. SQLCODE=-132, SQLSTATE=42824, DRIVER=4.17.30'

Answer (score 1):

Consider that column_a and column_b has trailing blanks and that there is an issue with `like` operand. You could always use `left()` and combine it with `RTRIM()`.  I've have very limited experience with DB2 but this is my hunch.

```
select  * 
from table1 T1
    INNER JOIN table2 T2 
    on LEFT(RTRIM(T1.column_a), LENGTH(RTRIM(T2.column_b))) = T2.column_b
```

Comment: This is closest answer but I'd bet the rtrim(t1.column_a) isn't needed for it  to work correctly.

Comment: I edited my answer because @Gouri stated that 'AN OPERAND OF LIKE IS NOT VALID.' If that is the case then my previous answer would fail also. Perhaps removing like will resolve the issue.

Comment: DB2 has a locate function too.  Where locate(trim(t2.column_b),t1.column_a) <> 0   but again the 2nd rtrim  isn't  needed.  Really close answer but I can't upvote again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @danny117. That's a lot cleaner. When I say limited experience, I'm talking 6 months 6 years ago. :) I removed the last RTRIM and I missed adding `INNER JOIN` probably missed something else. Thanks again.

Comment: AFAIK inner join is same as join  at least for this sample